# After uninstalling and reinstalling Ruby and Rails many ways, why can't get I get it to be found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, rbenv

For several days I have been struggling with a Rails app. I tried everything I could, asked some questions on SO and tried to gather all the information and tricks I could. Here's the summary:

Some days ago, when I ran `rails s`, I got the following, knowing I removed ruby-2.0.0-p0:

```
`require': dlopen(/Users/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6/lib/posix_spawn_ext.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/libruby.2.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
      Referenced from: /Users/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6/lib/posix_spawn_ext.bundle
      Reason: image not found - /Users/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6/lib/posix_spawn_ext.bundle
```

I was told on SO this could be related to RVM. I switched from RVM to rbenv, and I uninstalled/reinstalled Ruby (not the built-in OS X one) and Rails and got the same message when running `rails s`.

Then I uninstalled and deleted completely Macports and tried again with rbenv and got the same message.

I tried to symlink `/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/libruby.2.0.0.dylib` to `/usr/local`, I got the same message.

I tried playing around with exporting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` but I got the same message.

I uninstalled rbenv, Rails, and I returned to Macports and RVM, and I still get the same message.

Could some one help please?

I am using OS X.

`ruby -v outputs`  `ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]`
`rails -v outputs`  `Rails 3.2.13`

I deleted ruby-2.0.0-p0.

---

Edit:

`grep rvm ~/.bashrc` outputs:

```
PATH=$HOME/.rvm/bin:$PATH # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

`grep rvm ~/.bash_profile` outputs:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

`echo $PATH` outputs:

```
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin:/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/home/.rvm/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin:/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.16/site/bin:/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.16/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/ant/bin:/usr/local/mongodb/bin:/home/bin:/Users/otherhome/Desktop/Sites/apache-ant/bin:/usr/local/bro/bin:/opt/bro/bin
```

`gem env` outputs:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-05-14 patchlevel 195) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-12
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195
     - /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

`rvm info` outputs:

```
system:
    uname:       "Darwin MacBook-Pro-de-moi.local 12.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.4.0: Wed May  1 17:57:12 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.24.15~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
    system:      "osx/10.8/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)"
    zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 4.3.11 (i386-apple-darwin12.0)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.21.7 () by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "13 hours 8 minutes 18 seconds ago"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.0.0p195"
    date:         "2013-05-14"
    platform:     "x86_64-darwin12.4.0"
    patchlevel:   "2013-05-14 revision 40734"
    full_version: "ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195"
    ruby:         "/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin:/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/home/.rvm/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin:/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.16/site/bin:/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.16/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/ant/bin:/usr/local/mongodb/bin:/home/bin:/Users/otherhome/Desktop/Sites/apache-ant/bin:/usr/local/bro/bin:/opt/bro/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195:/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195"
    IRBRC:        "/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

`which ruby` outputs:

```
/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby
```

Comment: Append the output of these commands `grep rvm ~/.bashrc`, `grep rvm ~/.bash_profile`, `echo $PATH`, `gem env`, `rvm info` and `which ruby` to your question. We need to understand what your shell and Ruby think they know.

Comment: @theTinMan thanks for carrying of this question ;) I have edited my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you rails thinks it should use `--deployment` / or `--path` from bundler - it's the path to gems: `/Users/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems`, unfortunately bundler is nto smart enough and does not handle properly changes in ruby, you need to remove whole directory `rm -rf /Users/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle` and `bundle install` again.

I would recommend you stop using `--deployment` / or `--path` flags from bundler, remove the directories `rm -rf /Users/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle`, `rm -rf /Users/git/gitlab/.bundle/` and install gems in gemset, this way this problem will not happen again.

In case of capistrano deployments set this flags for `bundler/capistrano`:

```
set :bundle_dir, ''
set :bundle_flags, '--system --quiet'
```

to prevent using `--deployment` and `--path` flags with bundler.

Comment: thanks so much, several days trying to find out what was the problem:  it worked just fine !